# Check in array if only one specific entry is present

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to check if there is only one value in an array and if that specific value is "Home" then do something. Is the method below the best way to accomplish this or can I do it in one step?

Like:

```
$mymenu;    // array

if(count($mymenu) < 2 && in_array('Home', $mymenu)){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only other changes I'd make would be:

```
if(count($mymenu) === 1 && $mymenu[0] === 'Home')
```

Changing the `count` check from `< 2` to `=== 1` reads better to me; it makes more sense when reading the code back, since it conveys what you *actually* mean.

As for `in_array`, since you know there should only be one item in your array, it's probably faster to just use `$mymenu[0]` instead of doing a needle/haystack lookup.

Other than that, there isn't a more concise way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the info good to see I was on the right track. +1 and checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ternary Operator ...

```
echo count($mymenu) === 1 && $mymenu[0] === 'Home' ? 'Do something' : null;
```

Comment: I too love ternary expressions, but here, it's definitely overkill.